# I need my checkboxes to stay even after refresh

Tags: checkbox

I'm implementing a form and it basically has a few checkboxes. The form validation is in place and when there's an error, the page reloads. So in such scenario, the user checked checkboxes data is gone.

I'm looking for a way to keep the user checked boxes checked even after refresh

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MY NAME" value="1">
```

Thanks for your time and your help in advance!

cheers

Comment: What backend technology do you use?

Comment: solved it myself.. thank you :)